# Can a javascript if statement run without a function?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I dont know a whole lot about javascript and i was wondering if this script would run or do i need to put the "if statement" inside some kind of onPageLoad function to run this? Please help.

```
<script>
if (time<20)
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure it would run -- but it would depend on something else having run first so that `time` has a value.

For example, this would work (even though it's bad practice because it sets a property on `window`):

```
<script>
time = 10;
</script>

<script>
if (time<20)
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
```

You would also find it impossible to guarantee that any variables you need for temporary processing are kept out of the reach of other scripts. To overcome this limitation, you can (and except in the most trivial of sites, should) wrap the code inside an anonymous function that is invoked on the spot:

```
<script>
(function() {
    // your code here
})();
</script>
```

Comment: ***"it would depend on something else having run first so that time has a meaningful value"***, for that to be true `time` would first have to exist and it doesn't by default

Comment: @vol7ron That's exactly what Jon meant? His example clearly creates a global var as property of the window by not using the `var` keyword. Also, even if it had `var`, the piece of code is executing in the global scope so it'd become a property of window object nevertheless.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the way its phrased, a meaningful value means the variable already exists and doesn't have a value that works or that doesn't pass the condition.  That is not the case - `time` isn't a variable that even exists (global or local).  You're inferring something that isn't stated.  The OP clearly doesn't understand JS and should know that `time` must both (1) exist and (2) have a value < 20, to pass the condition.

Comment: @vol7ron I was referring to Jon's first code example. `time` is a property of the window, thus it exists in the global scope and has a numeric value lower than 20.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes, he does that (and he's right) but there are two things happening there that allow the code to run. 1) it's creating the variable 2) its setting it to a value that allows the condition to result as `true`.  All I'm saying is that the first part to that is not mentioned.  JS Engines usually break on error, thus it's important for the person to know. If jon sets `time=30` that still will not open the alert(), but the rest of the code (other scripts) will still run - that's the importance to what I'm saying.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it's what you meant. Guess it is useful to mention that the variable must be initialized first. Though the example is pretty clear. `=]` About errors that break scripts, I believe OP should be using Dev Tools console / Firebug to be aware of those.

Comment: @Jon: that is *most certainly* ***incorrect***.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Jgv25/  notice it doesn't alert.  Pop in a `window.time=undefined` before it and it will.  **IF `time` DOES NOT EXIST, IT IS AN ERROR AND WILL NOT CONTINUE.**

Comment: @Jon: if you specify `window.time` that is different; it is treating the variable as a property of window. If JS cannot find the variable in local scope, it tries to find it as a property of the window object, but if it does not, it treats it as a syntax error, where the variable does not exist.  When you specify it as a property, it reacts different - undeclared properties do not cause code to break.

Comment: @vol7ron: You are right, my mistake. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is all for the OP, just so he understands the difference between not setting `time` and setting it to a value that doesn't pass the `if` statement.  If that's all the JS on the page it may even appear to be equivalent, but JS errors are generally harder to diagnose/debug even with tools like firebug and Visual Studio's plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access DOM Elements you have to put the script tag at the end of the page. Or you use something like onload of the body tag (or an equivalent funciton in JS framework)

Answer (score 0):

It would run, realize `time` is undefined, generate an error and halt operations from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

If "time" is seted on server side, so, you may write onload property body dinamically like this:

```
<body onload="functionName(<?php echo()?>)">
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function functionName(time) {
        if(time < 30) { ... }
}
</script>
```